# How can I make my mysql query with many left joins execute quicker?

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a query and locally it's working fine. When it's live I am getting this error:

> ERROR 1104: The SELECT would examine too many records and probably
>   take a very long time. Check your WHERE and use SET OPTION
>   SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 if the SELECT is ok

I have added `SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1;`. It's working now, but it is running very slowly. Can any one sort out my query, ege instead of LEFT JOIN use another method. 
This is my query:

```
    SELECT sh.*,
       ps.provider_name,
       ps.photo_path AS photo
FROM   scholarship sh
       left join cat_category_sch ccs
              ON ccs.scholar_id = sh.id
       left join elg_countries_sch elg
              ON elg.scholar_id = sh.id
       left join study_level_sch sls
              ON sls.scholar_id = sh.id
       left join taken_country_sch tcs
              ON tcs.scholar_id = sh.id
       left join providers ps
              ON ps.id = sh.provider
       left join countires c1
              ON c1.id = elg.county_id
       left join countires c2
              ON c1.id = tcs.county_id
       left join study_level sl
              ON sl.id = sls.study_level_id
WHERE  sh.status = 1
       AND sh.ain_status = 1
       AND sh.deadline >= Date_sub(Now(), interval 1 year)
GROUP  BY sh.id
ORDER  BY sh.id DESC
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: For starters... the last three left join seem to be not useful, you're not using those data so you do not need to use them. This may improve a litlle the run time of the query.

Comment: Show us the table structures (with any indexes) and run an EXPLAIN against the query to show how MySQL is executing it

Comment: last 3 join also required because in some cases i have used where condition base on those tables so i put like this in above query i remove some where conditions. in every table i have maintain index(auto increment) as id

Answer (score 0):

LEFT implies that the 'right' table may not have a 'matching' row. Yet you don't check for existence or absence with IS NULL or IS NOT NULL.  So, I suspect LEFT is unnecessary?  (I bring the up because (1) it may distract from the real problem and (2) it may slow down the query.)

If LEFT is required, then `ON tcs.scholar_id = sh.id` needs an index on `scholar_id`.  (Etc.)

Also the compound index `INDEX(status, ain_status, deadline)` is likely to help.

Comment: Thank you for your  updation but i dint get you

Comment: 1. Add the index I suggested.  2. describe to us why you used LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN.

Comment: thank you @rick . in every table having index i.e. **id** (auto incremented). and i dont know which one is better either LEFT JOIN or JOIN

Comment: Try LEFT JOIN, as you have it; try JOIN.  See if there is any difference in ouput; there may not be.  Use LEFT JOIN when you want a row to come out, even if the _right_ table does not have a matching row.